# How to decide step size(sigma value) in MCMC routine related Cosmological Parameter estimation?

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, mathematics

I am running a modified Lambda-CDM in MCMC routine using Montepython and CLASS code, with aim to extract parameter values from Planck data.

In addition to the original 10-15 parameters for Planck data I have added 3 more. I am having doubt deciding the best step size for these new parameters. I am keeping original parameter mean values and step size as it is.

I know that- if the step size is too small then the value might settle in one of the local minimas(i.e doesn't span entire parameter space) which may not be the global minima and thus giving false results. However if the step size is too large then it may never settle consistently and give false results, again.

So how do I decide which is the best step size? Are there any estimation procedures or is it just trial and error?

NOTE- I know that small step sizes may give right results if they are run long enough. But I don't want to do this. I am running this in my laptop and it is already taking over 2 days  to complete 2 chains of decent sizes giving okish values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like a question for CS people.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It's computational physics or Mathemetics used in context of Cosmology. I learned the entire technique in course named 'Statistical Physics: A computational approach'.

Comment: I don't know your specific fitting algorithm, but I use machine learning quite a lot and usually, yes, it's trial and error. What you can do is have it run for a while and check if the parameter estimation (loss, likelihood...) is converging or oscillating. If it oscillates too much, your step size is too high. Modern optimisers can adaptively change the learning rate, but I don't know if they would fit your case.

Comment: sure but that's the physics question here?  'cuz it seems your problem is one of computational resources rather than conceptual physics.

Comment: Are you not using cosmomc? You should draw your step size for each parameter from its “proposal density”. Initially this is just your prior on the given parameter, but as your MCMC explores the space and begins to learn the joint distribution, the proposal density should be periodically updated to the current estimated density of each parameter, and the step size should be redrawn from this improved density. Cosmomc has this capability built in.